# a href button no action on click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, href

I am trying to make an href tag that has custom styling on it however when I click the button, I am not redirected to the link I have provided.  My button is:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com" class="btn btn-minier btn-info btn pull-right btn-padding">Connect Account</a>
```

I can see the link is on the button when I hover my mouse over the button however, nothing happens when I click it.  Any ideas on why this is happening?  Thanks anyone who knows what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You forgot the protocol, which is a must for external links.  Eg, add `http://` to your link, or `https://`, and it will work fine.

Comment: I through it in there and still nothing.  I then moved my button outside of my <div> at the bottom of the page and it works fine

Comment: Then you have js interfering with your html events.  Either way, the protocol is required for external links, so leave it in there.  That aside, though, what other js do you have on the page?  I tested the above html in a personal Bootstrap project of mine, and it works fine there.

Comment: If this is a result of you having your href inside another div, then make sure that div doesn't have another mousedown or click handler on it that would block input flow to the children (e.g. mousedown returns false or prevents propagation, etc)  Also make sure you don't have any script errors in your debugger during the click, it could be that the div tries to do something and fails so it bails out early.

Comment: a LOT, I am running a ruby on rails app, so my javascript/jquery depends are running site wide in my application.html.erb and I have no control over them.  I think you are right though! this href is inside a very jq/js heavy drop down container